# Get already set value in flutter from drop down list widget from another class?

Tags: android, flutter, drop-down-menu

I have to get value from drop down list widget from another class?
This is the widget class:

```
`
class LocationAccuracyButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const LocationAccuracyButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_LocationAccuracyButtonWidgetState createState() =>
_LocationAccuracyButtonWidgetState();
}

class _LocationAccuracyButtonWidgetState
extends State<LocationAccuracyButtonWidget> {
late LocationAccuracyButtonModel _model;

@override
void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
super.setState(callback);
_model.onUpdate();
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
model = createModel(context, () => LocationAccuracyButtonModel());

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => setState(() {}));
}

@override
void dispose() {
_model.maybeDispose();

super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
context.watch<FFAppState>();

return Padding(
padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
child: FlutterFlowDropDown<String>(
controller: _model.locationAccuracyButtonController ??=
FormFieldController<String>(
_model.locationAccuracyButtonValue ??= 'bestForNavigation',
),
options: [
'bestForNavigation',
'best',
'high',
'medium',
'low',
'lowest'
],
optionLabels: [
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'fg96g7pn' /* Najlepsza do nawigacji /,
),
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'029obznb' / Najlepsza /,
),
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'xqwvtwml' / Wysoka /,
),
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'7sic8f12' / Średnia /,
),
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'xgoc2cb4' / Niska /,
),
FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
'nsft4j78' / Najniższa */,
)
],
onChanged: (val) =>
setState(() => _model.locationAccuracyButtonValue = val), 
`
```

I'm stuck in this

I need to access
options: [
'bestForNavigation',
'best',
'high',
'medium',
'low',
'lowest'
from another class. How to do this?

I try get model:
LocationAccuracyButtonModel accuracyButtonModel = LocationAccuracyButtonModel();
med = accuracyButtonModel.locationAccuracyButtonController... ?